Matplotlib antialiasing of axvline when plotting from label encoded classes when it's zoomed in
I have this code:
# Display parameter
Xt = X_test[0, 0:1024]
a = 1
lw = 1

# Get mask of every classes
bl_pred = yp == 0
p_pred = yp == 1
qrs_pred = yp == 2
t_pred = yp == 3

# Plotting
for i in range(len(Xt)):
  if bl_pred[i]:
    plt.axvline(x=i, color='grey', linestyle='-', alpha=a, linewidth=lw)
  elif p_pred[i]:
    plt.axvline(x=i, color='orange', linestyle='-', alpha=a, linewidth=lw)
  elif qrs_pred[i]:
    plt.axvline(x=i, color='green', linestyle='-', alpha=a, linewidth=lw)
  elif t_pred[i]:
    plt.axvline(x=i, color='purple', linestyle='-', alpha=a, linewidth=lw)
plt.plot(Xt, color='blue')

plt.show()

Returning Image without problem:

But as I zoomed in the data scope to the smaller scope like this:
# Display parameter
Xt = X_test[0, 0:256] # smaller scope
a = 1
lw = 1

It's returning aliased image:

This can be fixed with increasing linewidth:
# Display parameter
Xt = X_test[0, 0:256]
a = 1
lw = 1.4 # increasing line width manually


But, I don't want manually adjusting line width. How do I make it automatically adjust? Maybe it can be calculated based on difference of every nodes of current display? But I don't know the syntax for that.

Maybe you could try to plot rectangles instead: plt.axvspan(i-0.5, i+0.5, ....)

Thanks @JohanC
It's worked using axvspan
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Display parameter
Xt = X_test[0, :256]
a = 0.5

# Get mask of every class
bl_pred = yp == 0
p_pred = yp == 1
qrs_pred = yp == 2
t_pred = yp == 3

# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
prev_class = None
start_idx = 0

for i in range(len(Xt)):
    current_class = None
    if bl_pred[i]:
        current_class = 'grey'
    elif p_pred[i]:
        current_class = 'orange'
    elif qrs_pred[i]:
        current_class = 'green'
    elif t_pred[i]:
        current_class = 'purple'

    if current_class != prev_class:
        if prev_class is not None:
            ax.axvspan(start_idx, i, color=prev_class, alpha=a)
        start_idx = i
        prev_class = current_class

# Fill the last region
if prev_class is not None:
    ax.axvspan(start_idx, len(Xt), color=prev_class, alpha=a)

ax.plot(Xt, color='blue')
plt.show()

Returning:

This is yp[:256] which label encoded prediction in case you are wondering there is misclassifiation in ground truth 2, which classified as 3 (purple).
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)

